# Nested redux-forms: voucher form inside checkout form

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to make a checkout page with a nested coupon code / voucher subform using redux-form.

So the checkout form would include for example a Country selection and inside this form I'd like to add a sub form to apply a Voucher.

The user needs to be able to apply a voucher separately from the main checkout form to view the possible discount.

When submitting the general checkout form the voucher must also be validated in case it wasn't applied.

What would be the best way to implement this?

I understand I can't simply nest reduxForms. I don't want to create 2 seperate forms, because i'd like to show possible validation and submit errors of the general checkout form also below  the voucher field
I might be able to use asyncValidation for the voucher field, but I'd like to trigger that with a apply button instead of a field blur.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I've implemented this using asyncValidation. To trigger this, not when leaving the voucher field but when clicking the apply button I created a custom Field component with the textfield and button. The textfield gets the whole input except the onBlur function, the button's click handler calls the input.onBlur. 
Because it's a field I could also easily use the meta information to disable the button when appropriate.

Feels like quite a hack, so better solutions are welcome.

Comment: One alternative way would by manually calling the form's asyncValidate. http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/Props.md/#-asyncvalidate-function-
But then, especially if you need multiple async validations, you have to retrieve from somewhere else which part is being validated so you can for example disable the button.